# Return a value other than the class in ES6

Tags: javascript, constructor, ecmascript-6

Recently I've been testing out classes with ES6, I've noticed that when creating a class you cannot specify the value given by the constructor.

Previously in ES5 this was possible.

In both cases I would instantiate the class with `new MyClass`
The reason I want to do this is so I can return a subset of the current class with only functions on it.

### ES5 - returns `My class was init with: Blah`

```
var MyClass = function() {
  this.initVar = 'Blah'

  return 'My Class was init with: ' + this.initVar
}
```

### ES6 - returns `{}`

```
class Bob {
  constructor() {
   return 'hello' 
  }
}
```

Comment: It will be very confusing if you call an ES6 Class and a constructor function "class". They are distinctly different things. If the *MyClass* function is called with *new*, it will not return what you think it returns—it returns the object referenced by *this*, not the string you have in the return statement, see [*ECMA-262 §13.2.2*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.2).

Comment: @RobG: Hmm, classes are just syntactic sugar for constructor functions, so they should actually be the same thing.

Comment: @FelixKling—sure, but the syntax is quite different. I just think there needs to be a simple way to differentiate which pattern is being used. Perhaps "ES6 classes" vs "traditional constructors"?

Comment: I think I understand your question now: "can an ES6 class return an object other than *this*"?

Comment: @RobG Yeah basically, after some fooling around I've found that you can indeed return an object other than this provided its an object and not a primitive. However if you inherit from that object the behaviour is lost and the constructor returns the object instead of what you defined to return.

Comment: @Snowfiring—have a look at how *extends* is used in Jack Franklin's [*An introduction to ES6 classes*](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2014/07/introduction-to-es6-classes-tutorial/), it seems to do what you want.

Comment: @RobG View this [fiddle](http://www.es6fiddle.net/i51qta7z/) it will show the issue I'm having. It seems that extended classes loose there return

Comment: @Snowfiring Not even in ES5 it did return a primitive string if you called your constructor with `new`. `new` *always* returns an object.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

According to the [*Class* article](http://tc39wiki.calculist.org/es6/classes/) from the TC39 web site, the ES6 class syntax has an implicit constructor function that is called if no such function is provided in the class definition.

This can be overridden by providing your own constructor and returning whatever object you want, e.g.:

```
class Bob {
  constructor(name) {
    return {hi: name};  // returns an object other than *this*.
  }
}
```

In action:

```
var bob = new Bob('bob');
console.log(bob.hi); // 'bob'
```

To extend the class, you can do:

```
class Bill extends Bob {
}
```

However *extends* also has an implicit constructor, so it will return a new instance of *Bill* that inherits from *Bob.prototype*. Since *hi* was defined in the constructor and not inherited, you get:

```
var bill = new Bill('bill');
console.log(bill.hi);  // undefined
```

To initialise Bill the same as *Bob*, provide a constructor that calls *super*. This call also changes the *this* object of *Bill* to the value returned by *super*, e.g.

```
class Bill extends Bob {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
  }
}
```

Now:

```
var bill = new Bill('bill');
console.log(bill.hi); // bill
```

Also worth noting that the body of a *classDeclaration* is always [*strict mode code*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-strict-mode-code).

As a runnable snippet:

```js
class Bob {
  constructor(name) {
    return {hi: name};  // returns an object other than *this*.
  }
}

var bob = new Bob('bob');
console.log(bob.hi); // 'bob'

class Bill extends Bob {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
  }
}

var bill = new Bill('bill');
console.log(bill.hi); // bill
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusion about the workaround, thanks for the extra info. Do you have any info on why the spec is like this. It seems odd for a extended class to have a different return value should you not define a constructor.

Comment: @RobG, it worth mentioning that `class Bill` doesn't have to return but just call the super will do the same. The return of the super call will change this reference.

Comment: Further background: the creators of JavaScript discussed the issue of constructor return-values in 2014 here: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/should-the-default-constructor-return-the-return-value-of-super. Brendan Eich, the original creator of the language, was, at least at the time, in favour of continuing to allow return values, saying "We did discuss return expr; in constructors at the TC39 meeting, and my sense is that we want to keep that option. Classes as sugar (mostly), and all that."

Answer (score 2):

The `ES6` actually does not return `{}` but the class *(constructor)* object in that case. The class constructor can return objects, but not primitive values. So instead of [String] `"hello"` it returns [Object] `Bob`. Any value can be returned this way:

```
class Bob {
  constructor() {
   return ()=>'hello';
  }
}
const bob = new Bob()();
```

The returned [Function], as it is an object, can be returned and immediately fired to return some primitive value, eg. [String] `"hello"`.

Answer (score 0):

Compare these fiddles: [es5](http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/ronescxk/1/) and
[es6](http://www.es6fiddle.net/i4zj5706/)

What you say was possible in es5 is still possible in es6, there is a small thing that if you use new keyword, then a new object for that class is created and if you dont ue new then the function is executed.

1. So when you say, `var x=  Bob();` in both es5 and es6, you execute the constructor function, not create a new object, thus it returns something.
2. And when you say,`var x= new Bob();`, you get a new object, initialised by the constructor function.

This is applicable to both es5 and es6, as es6 classes does nothing new , but are introduced just for the sake of syntax.

**Edit**: In case of extending classes:
You can not just extend a class in es6 and expect that the super constructor is called, you need to call it explicitly inside the child class constructor.. see the code:

```
class Bob {
  constructor() {
    return {hi: 'bob'}
  }
}

class Bill extends Bob {
  constructor() {
   return super();// here you should retun the called super constructer
  }
}

var x=  Bob();
console.log(Bob);

 x= new Bill();
console.log(x.hi);
```

This is why, [this](http://es6fiddle.net/i50npw4w) doesnt work, but [this](http://www.es6fiddle.net/i53kk4ev/) works..

Comment: You are correct however both ES6 and ES5 allow you to return objects when called with `new`. However for some reason this behaviour is lost when extending the class see http://www.es6fiddle.net/i50npw4w/

Comment: @Snowfiring .. see.. again, you need to call the super constructor in case of inheritance with classes in es6.. edited my answer.. please look.

Comment: "This is applicable to both es5 and es6" In ES6 calling a class as a function results in an error. The ES6 fiddle you link to throws errors because of this.

Comment: When I try any of the examples above without 'new' I get `Class constructor ... cannot be invoked without 'new'`