# Can someone explain why this JavaScript code errors out on JSBin on iPad (Safari)? Although it works on a desktop browser

Tags: javascript, ios, jsbin

https://gist.github.com/fernandozamoraj/4788c233441be54c825b83a6e73d7205

When I run the script on jsbin it shows an error but no details. I've ran it through jslint but that didn't help much. I did this from my iPad.

I realize that the script has some rookie errors.  Try not to focus on that.  My question is why it works on Google Chrome on my Windows 10 Box but not on Safari browser on iPad (iOS 10.2.1).

Comment: Why are you returning from a constructor...? When you try to call the return function with `ML$("hi")` there is no function to call because the function isn't returned from the constructor...

Comment: I have no problems running it on jsbin. but if you be aware that the code will likely have different behaviour under ES5 and ES6
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980996/return-a-value-other-than-the-class-in-es6

Comment: Andrew Li - please read the code it sets the global member ML$ to a function... Therefore ML$ exists in the global.  The code does work on my desktop.  I hadn't checked it on a desktop browser. It was getting an error on iPad's Safari Browser.